# Why am I sporadically being returned a NoneType Error?

Tags: python, pandas, object, attributes, nonetype

I am having trouble understanding the origins of the **Attribute Error: None Type** for my program. I am running a series of simulations and the majority of the time when I run <50 loops, the error does not come up. However, occasionally, or on larger simulations I am returned an error, which will say...

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'regular_score'
```

These attributes have been instantiated earlier and are working correctly for the majority of the simulation.

The aim of the project is to return a DataFrame with a summary of all the simulations. Below is a *subset* of the DataFrame.

```
                  Projected Finish  Chance of Finals  Chance at a Bye  Chance of First  Chance of Last
Player_A              3.88                     80.0             36.0         40.0         0.0
Player_B              4.56                     76.0             28.0         12.0         8.0
Player_C              5.40                     68.0             20.0         4.0          12.0
Player_D              5.72                     60.0             12.0         4.0          8.0
Player_E              5.88                     64.0             12.0         4.0          20.0
```

The traceback for the error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/tomrogers/Desktop/Python/primary/tempCodeRunnerFile.py", line 512, in <module>
    finishing_postions(250)
  File "/Users/tomrogers/Desktop/Python/primary/tempCodeRunnerFile.py", line 454, in finishing_postions
    winner.append(grand_final())
  File "/Users/tomrogers/Desktop/Python/primary/tempCodeRunnerFile.py", line 373, in grand_final
    player_1 = first_preliminary()
  File "/Users/tomrogers/Desktop/Python/primary/tempCodeRunnerFile.py", line 350, in first_preliminary
    player_2_score = player_2.regular_score()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'regular_score'
```

Which is pointing to this function, but as you can see I am not calling a non-existent attribute.

```
def grand_final():

    player_1 = first_preliminary()
    player_2 = second_preliminary()

    # print(
    #     f"{'Simulating Grand Final'} {'Between' + ' ' + player_1.name + ' & ' + player_2.name} ")
    player_1_score = player_1.regular_score()
    player_2_score = player_2.regular_score()

    if player_1_score > player_2_score:
        return player_1.name
    if player_2_score > player_1_score:
        return player_2.name
```

My understanding of this is there seems to be a variable being called which does not have the attribute, but when the loop successfully runs through 25 simulations or so, no error shows up and the Chance of First / Chance of Last columns both = 100, which would suggest there is no hidden variable being called.

Here is an example of one of 10 objects, all 10 follow the same sequence.

```
Player_A = TL(name='Player A', scores=np.array([]))
```

I did think of a try, except sequence to catch the error, but I'm not sure how that would work with returning a NoneType.

Do let me know if I can provide some more details.

Thanks a heap!

Edit:

```
def second_preliminary():
    player_1 = eval(ladder['Coach'].iloc[1])
    player_2 = second_elimination()

    player_1_score = player_1.regular_score()
    player_2_score = player_2.regular_score()

    if player_1_score > player_2_score:
         return player_1
    if player_2_score > player_1_score:
         return player_2

def second_elimination():
""" simulate the finals """

    player_1 = eval(ladder['Coach'].iloc[2])
    player_2 = eval(ladder['Coach'].iloc[4])

    player_1_score = player_1.regular_score()
    player_2_score = player_2.regular_score()

    if player_1_score > player_2_score:
         return player_1
    if player_2_score > player_1_score:
         return player_2
```

A sample of the returned ladder for one simulation is:

```
print(ladder)

           Coach     F     A     Pct  Pts
Team                                             
Player_A   Player A  7316  7023  104.17   16
Player_B   Player B  7619  7436  102.46   16
Player_C   Player C  7524  7272  103.47   12
Player_D   Player D  7116  7102  100.20   12
Player_E   Player E  7343  7593   96.71   12
Player_F   Player F  7616  7276  104.67    8
Player_G   Player G  7763  7532  103.07    8
Player_H   Player H  7507  7342  102.25    8
Player_I   Player I  7111  7681   92.58    8
Player_J   Player J  7244  7902   91.67    0
```

Comment: whats the contents of this function `second_preliminary()` whats happening here is that when calling `player_2 = second_preliminary()` you must have some use case which results in nothing returned I.E `None`

Comment: Hi Chris. Thanks for commenting, I'll add the sequence of functions it's calling back to in the body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I've solved the issue, I think it's related to an oversight in some functions where I've accidentally called two if statements instead of if, elif, else. Once I rectified that I have no longer encountered the issue.

Thanks!